# Error in executing the Jar file in command Pompt (Gradle Build): NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle

I am building a Java Project using Gradle Build. The project has some external dependencies like Apache POI, Spring Core/Context, Log4j. When I run the project in my IDE , it is compiling and executing successfully without any errors.
However, when I build the Jar file using gradle build and run it in command prompt (using "java -jar file-name") I get Error -

**NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook**

Here is the my build.gradle file -

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies{
        classpath group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.0.2.RELEASE'
        classpath group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.0.2.RELEASE'
        classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.17'
        classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17'
        classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.17'
        classpath group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
        classpath group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: '2.6.0'
    }
 }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

mainClassName = '<package>.HelloWorld'

dependencies{

    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.17'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.17'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0'

}

jar {
    manifest{
        attributes '<package>.HelloWorld'
    }
    baseName = 'finder-app'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
```

The dependency jar files are present on my local machine.

Do I need to add the jar files when I package the jar using build.gradle? If yes, then how? OR

Do I need to add CLASSPATH (to external jar directory) to my local machine environment variable?

Comment: What command are you executing to run the jar ?

Comment: java -jar finder-app-0.1.0.jar

Comment: In your jar, META-INF/manifest, is the classpath set correctly?

Comment: There might be an issue with my manifest file. Not sure though. Here are the contents of META-INF/manifest file (its basically the path to my main class) -

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: <package>.HelloWorld

Comment: @KetanDeopujari, check out this article, "http://www.anexinet.com/blog/six-ways-to-package-a-java-application-with-gradle/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following `build.gradle`, it would deliver a [uber jar](http://www.anexinet.com/blog/six-ways-to-package-a-java-application-with-gradle/), which package all the dependencies ([doc reference](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#integrating_with_application_plugin)).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

mainClassName = "com.github.Library"

dependencies{
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.17'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.17'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0'
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'finder-app'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
```

Just run `./gradlew :shadowJar`, and then you can run `java -jar build/libs/finder-app-0.1.0-all.jar`. It would work for your favor.

NOTE, you dont need so many irrelevant dependencies in your `buildscript{}`, those are serves for plugins usage.

Answer (score 0):

To run a java application you need to provide a classpath
You have two options:

- provide the classpath in the jar manifest (META-INF/manifest) then you can run your jar using

  java -jar myjar.jar
- provide the classpath using -cp parameter then you can run your jar using

java -cp list_of_dependencies_jar_and_main_jar package.MyMainClass